# How to remove spaces from a textfield and a filecont expression

Tags: java, textfield, spaces

i have been looking through the different questions as to "how to remove spaces" from various stuff, and i get the basics of it, the problem is that i cant find a way to get it done in my code, as it is a bit tricky to "just" add a function to trim the spaces away.

```
public static ArrayList<String> searchForSong(String path) {
    ArrayList<String> matchingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    for (File f : files) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                        f.getAbsolutePath()); // laver en stream baseret på
                // en fil
                int b; // til at putte bytes i
                StringBuilder fileCont = new StringBuilder(); // for at
                // sætte
                // bytes'ne
                // sammen
                // til en
                // string

                while ((b = fis.read()) != -1) // så længe den ikke er -1
                // (EOF).. læs!
                {
                    fileCont.append((char) b);// put byten i stringbuilderen
                }
                // System.out.println(fileCont.toString()); //skriv
                // string'en/filens indhold ud..
                if (fileCont.toString().toLowerCase().contains(jTextFieldSearch.getText().toLowerCase())) {
                    matchingFiles.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // skal på, fordi
                // FileInputStream smider
                // FileNotFoundException
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) { // skal på, fordi fis.read() smider
                // IOException
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return matchingFiles;
}
```

In this code i would like two strings to have removed their spaces the one called `fileCont.toString()` and `jTextFieldSearch.getText`

Anyone who can help? it would be really great!

Comment: What spaces? leading/trailing, all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if statment like this...

```
if (fileCont.toString().replaceAll("\\s","").toLowerCase().contains(jTextFieldSearch.getText().replaceAll("\\s","").toLowerCase())) {
    matchingFiles.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: Oh.. didnt know i could incorporate it like that, awesome! thanks! :):

Answer (score 0):

To remove just leading/trailing spaces you can use trim: `fileCont.toString().trim();`

to remove all spaces everywhere in the string, you can use replace:  `fileCont.toString().replaceAll("\\s","");`

Comment: '\' is an escape character in java, when using with regular expressions you have to use '\\'